# Changing Django template context with Javascript

Tags: javascript, django, django-templates

Is it possible to change the HTML rendered by Django by changing the variables (context) with Javascript?

For example, say I render, `{{ item }}`, can I hide everything rendered by `{{ item }}` by hiding the Django variable itself? Or do I have to select the rendered HTML at that point. How do Django's context preprocessors work with Javascript?

Answer (score 0):

You have to remember that JavaScript runs **AFTER** the HTML is rendered. So no it's not possible to do what you want (changing Django variable with JS).

If you want to hide content of {{ item }}, wrap it in a HTML element then select and hide it with JS.

Hope it helps.